# Pandas - How to find number of equipment failures and the corresponding downtime for each failure

Tags: python, pandas

I have some test data which looks like this:

```
test_data = {'equipment_barcode': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002', '0002'], 
         'date': ['2022-04-16', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-19', '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16'],
         'downtime_minutes':[1200, 240, 1440, 600, 360, 1440, 1440, 180]}
```

I have converted this into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)

print(df)

    equipment_barcode   date          downtime_minutes
0   0001                2022-04-16    1200
1   0001                2022-04-17    240
2   0001                2022-04-18    1440
3   0001                2022-04-19    600
4   0002                2022-05-13    360
5   0002                2022-05-14    1440
6   0002                2022-05-15    1440
7   0002                2022-05-16    180
```

There are 1,440 minutes in one day. This information is required to calculate the NUMBER of faults. A fault may occur over consecutive number of days and thus will still be counted as ONE fault only.

The task is to find the number of faults for each equipment_barcode. For example equipment 0001 had 2 faults [one fault on 16th of April lasting for 1200 minutes and one fault on 17th-19th of April lasting for 2280 minutes(240 + 1440 + 600)].

For added clarity; equipment 0002 had 1 fault [fault on 13th-16th of May lasting for 3420 minutes (360 + 1440 + 1440 + 180)].

In the end I would like a resulting dataframe that shows something like this:

```
    equipment_barcode   fault_number    total_downtime_minutes
0   0001                1               1200
1   0001                2               2280
2   0002                1               3420
```

---

UPDATE: The question is still unsolved :( I will include a picture to explain the logic more clearly.

The idea is to count every single row in the original dataframe as one fault **UNLESS** we come across this pattern:

[Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkouu.png)

So if we now apply the logic shown in the image above:

We can say that row 0 is ONE fault because we have to count every single row as a fault until the pattern appears.

Rows 1-3 follow the pattern (a = 240, b = 600, and the value in the middle is 1440; the dates are consecutive; the equipment barcode number is the same), therefore these rows will count as ONE fault.

Rows 4-7 follow the pattern (a = 360, b = 180, and the values in the middle are 1440; the dates are consecutive; the equipment barcode number is the same), therefore these rows will count as ONE fault.

Comment: in your expected output, is 'total_downtime_minutes' the accumulated sum?

Comment: Hi @Henrik, yes the sum is accumulated for EACH fault. Row 0 of the df is the 1st fault, rows 1 ,2 and 3 are the 2nd fault (for equipment 0001). For equipment 0002, rows 4,5,6 and 7 are the 1st fault. I hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
test_data = {
    'equipment_barcode': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002', '0002'],
    'date': ['2022-04-15', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-19', '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16'],
    'downtime_minutes':[1200, 240, 1440, 600, 360, 1440, 1440, 180]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dt = df['date']
day = pd.Timedelta('1d')
breaks = dt.diff() != day
groups = breaks.cumsum()
df['groups'] = groups
dft = df.groupby(by=['equipment_barcode', 'groups'])['downtime_minutes'].sum().reset_index()
dft = dft.drop('groups', axis=1)
dft['fault_number'] = dft.groupby(by='equipment_barcode').cumcount() + 1
print(dft)
```

Output:

```
  equipment_barcode  downtime_minutes  fault_number
0              0001              1200             1
1              0001              2280             2
2              0002              3420             1
```

Comment: Hello @Jeril, thank you for this. I will try your code on my actual data and see if it will give me the desired output. I will give feedback soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Jeril, the first date in test_data is wrong, it should be '2022-04-16' instead of  '2022-04-15'. The fault on 2022-04-16 lasted for 20 hours (1200 minutes). I do not get the desired output when the correct date is used: I get 1 fault for equipment 0001 with a cumulative downtime of 3480 minutes which is wrong. There should be 2 faults for equipment 00001: 1st fault lasting 1200 minutes and the 2nd fault lasting 2280 minutes.

Change the first date to 2022-04-16, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Question has been updated, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
data = {'equipment_barcode': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0001',
                              '0002', '0002', '0002', '0002'], 
        'date': ['2022-04-16', '2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-19',
                 '2022-05-13', '2022-05-14', '2022-05-15', '2022-05-16'],
        'downtime_minutes':[1200, 240, 1440, 600, 360, 1440, 1440, 180]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype({'date': 'datetime64[ns]'})
df
'''
  equipment_barcode        date  downtime_minutes
0              0001  2022-04-16              1200
1              0001  2022-04-17               240
2              0001  2022-04-18              1440
3              0001  2022-04-19               600
4              0002  2022-05-13               360
5              0002  2022-05-14              1440
6              0002  2022-05-15              1440
7              0002  2022-05-16               180
'''

df.dtypes
'''
equipment_barcode            object
date                 datetime64[ns]
downtime_minutes              int64
dtype: object
'''
```

then:

```py
def func(grp: pd.DataFrame):
    return (
        grp.assign(fault_number=lambda x: x.date.diff() != pd.Timedelta('1d'))
        .assign(fault_number=lambda x: x.fault_number.cumsum())
        .groupby('fault_number')
        .agg(downtime_minutes=('downtime_minutes', sum))
    )

# code
(
    df.astype({'date': 'datetime64[ns]'})
    .groupby(['equipment_barcode'])
    .apply(func)
    .reset_index()
)
'''
  equipment_barcode  fault_number  downtime_minutes
0              0001             1              1200
1              0001             2              2280
2              0002             1              3420
'''
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the first date in the data dictionary should be 2022-04-16. When the correct date is used the output is incorrect:

I get 1 fault for equipment 0001 with a cumulative downtime of 3480 minutes which is wrong. There should be 2 faults for equipment 00001: 1st fault lasting 1200 minutes and the 2nd fault lasting 2280 minutes. Change the first date to 2022-04-16, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: But what is logic?

Comment: The logic is that not every row counts as a fault, if we see a value of 1440 in the downtime_minutes column, it means that the fault started earlier and ended when a non 1440 value occurred. I hope this makes sense..

Comment: The dataset I have does not include the timings of when the faults occurred (annoyingly). For row 0, the fault could have occurred at 3am and finished at 11pm (20hrs or 1200 minutes),

for rows 1,2,3 the fault started at 8pm on 17th April and ended on 19th April at 10am (total 2280 minutes or 38 hours). I hope this clarifies the logic.

Comment: @python_pandas_user The answer has been updated!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much!! I'll try this code on my actual real-life data and see if I get the output desired. I'll revert back to you soon for feedback :)

Comment: Hi Qinghui, When using your code, I do not get the output you have put at the bottom, instead I get only 1 fault for equipment 0001. I will update the original question and give a little bit more information regarding the logic.

Comment: Question has been updated, please have a look.